# How to ignore parameter pack arguments

Tags: c++, parameter-pack

With the expression
`(void)var;` we can effectively disable unused variable warnings.

However, how does that work with arguments in a parameter pack?

```
template<bool Debug = DebugMode, typename... Arg>
void log_debug(const Arg&... args) {
    if constexpr(Debug) {
        (std::clog << ... << args) << std::endl;
    } else {
        //ignore the arguments willingly when not in debug
        (void)args; // does not compile
    }
}
```

Comment: OT, but please note that parameter pack functions are *not* the same as variadic functions. Variadic functions are the old C functions like `printf` or similar.

Comment: Which compiler gives you a warning for this code (with `(void)args;` removed)? They shouldn't do that in a `if constexpr` branch like this. You are using `args` in the other branch.

Comment: What nuisance are you experiencing when you simply delete the entire `else` block in this  specific code when actually called? Your question should include that as part of a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `maybe_unused`:

```cpp
template<bool Debug = DebugMode, typename... Arg>
void log_debug([[maybe_unused]] Arg&&... args) {
```

If you for some reason don't want that, you could make a fold expression over the comma operator in your `else`:

```cpp
} else {
    (..., (void)args);
}
```